# Convert nested table from asxml, asjson or html to string

Tags: html, xml, xslt, type-conversion, abap

How to transform asjson, asxml or an html table to a string while considering this: the string should be prepared in a way to be rendered "like a table", i. e. columns and the cells, especially nested tables with their header lines and cells, should be displayed in a well readable fashion. The string should be "built" and rendered to resemble such an HTML example (respecting also nested tables with their header lines, without borders):

```html
<table border = "1px solid black;">
   <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <p>test</p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <table border = "1px solid black;">
            <tr>
               <th>header1</th>
               <th>header2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>A</td>
               <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>C</td>
               <td>D</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>
         <table border = "1px solid black;">
            <tr>
               <th>header1</th>
               <th>header2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>E</td>
               <td>F</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>G</td>
               <td>H</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Asking for recommendations is to be well documented to avoid [subjective question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), but you can refine your question. There are lots of ways to do it in ABAP. You may wish to look at them and refine your question if needed. One of the possible solutions is `CALL TRANSFORMATION` (XSLT or Simple Transformation). `ID` being a generic identity transformation between variable and ASXML format.

Comment: The question is refined. The input to work with is the outcome of CALL TRANSFORMATION.

Comment: You can use XSLT or Simple Transformation (ST), so it's not possible to give a precise answer. You have to choose one or the other. You also have lots of examples in the Web (for instance let's take SAP proprietary ST language [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenst_table_abexa.htm)), so you could try first, and revert back if you have a precise question?